# Issue in Liferay 6.1 Integration with Solr 4.0

Tags: search, solr, liferay

I tried to Integrate Solr 4 with Liferay 6.1 in windows. But I am getting Permission denied error when i try to create a collection. I have given full permission to the folder named SOLR.

Please find the below logs.
Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

```
    INFO: Creating Collection : name=liferay&action=CREATE&numShards=2
    Feb 07, 2017 2:44:15 PM org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor createCollection
    INFO: Create collection liferay on [W10368:8983_solr]
    Feb 07, 2017 2:44:15 PM org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor createCollection
    SEVERE: Error talking to shard: W10368:8983/solr
    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://W10368:8983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:413)        
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

    Feb 07, 2017 2:44:16 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
    SEVERE: Collection creation of liferay failed
```

On top of that, after deploying Solr plugin and when i restart my Portal server, I am getting this below error. I tried to change the zookeeper jar version to 4.6 but still I am getting same issue.Is anyone aware why is it happening?

```
    21:45:47,256 ERROR [liferay/search_writer/SYSTEM_ENGINE-1][SolrIndexWriterImpl:147] java.lang.RuntimeException
    java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:83)
```

Comment: Is W10368:8983 an external server?IOException occured when talking to server,seems like connection issue with the server?Possible proxy issue connecting to external machine

Comment: No.. It is the local server.